# Eclipse Jetty won't start

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I've tried a lot, but Jetty just would not start, here's the config in the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>8080</port>
        </httpConnector>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then running it using `mvn jetty:run`

All that happens is this:

```
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.15.v20160210:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ app <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.15.v20160210:run (default-cli) @ app ---
[INFO] Logging initialized @4357ms
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: app
[INFO] Skipping Jetty start: jetty.skip==true
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.448 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-10T14:09:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

I did the changes based on @joakim-erdfelt and here's the error now:

```
java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@584ca390{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @66842ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different versions of jetty going on ...

```xml
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
```

and ...

```
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.15.v20160210:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ app <<<
```

Correct your dependencies / plugins / etc so that you are using the same version of Jetty.

You also have a `<configuration>` set that is skipping the execution.

```
[INFO] Skipping Jetty start: jetty.skip==true
```

You'll want to address why you have that configuration set.

Comment: Thanks, however now I get this: java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations

Comment: that's too generic to work with.  that could come from any library that does annotation scanning (servlet / spring / cdi / hibernate / jpa / etc ...)

Comment: It's coming from  `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:577)`

Comment: Probably have a large `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` collection (or a huge maven classpath).  You can configure the `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait` (property/attribute) on the context, server, or system property to a value over 60. (in seconds) to wait for complete annotation scan.  It cannot be disabled, only set higher.